# how to solve a higher order boundary conditioned differential equation with matlab function

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, numerical-analysis

I'm trying to solve a boundary value condition problem with matlab bvp4c function. But I get warning and it doesn't give correct solution.
my equation is d4y/dx4=C/(ax^2 -y)^2 ,C and a are constant , my warning content is following below

**Warning: Unable to meet the tolerance without using more than 2500 mesh points.
The last mesh of 2152 points and the solution are available in the output argument.
The maximum residual is 9.25647e+11, while requested accuracy is 0.001.**

my code:

```
clc;clear
solinit = bvpinit([0,200],[1,1,1,1]);
sol = bvp4c(@deriv,@bcs,solinit);
plot(sol.x,sol.y)
function dydx = deriv(x,y)

c=1;a=1;
dydx = [y(2)
        y(3)
        y(4)
       (c/(a*x.^2 -y(1)).^2)];
end

function res = bcs(ya,yb)
res = [ ya(1) 
        ya(2)
        yb(3)
        yb(4)];
end
```

I don't know what is its reason?!
thanks in advance for your helping
[image]

Comment: Your initial guess gives a singularity at `x=1`, try again with `solinit = bvpinit([0,200],[-1,0,0,0]);`. No guarantee, but perhaps that will give a different error. Note that `y(0)=y'(0)=0` forces any solution to be singular at `x=0`, so you might want to try to find a more theoretical approximation around that point.

Comment: hi,thank you but it doesn't work ,  What do you think about constants?

Comment: What kind of equation is this, is there some reason from a connection to a physical model or similar that makes the existence of a solution probable?

Comment: I really do not know, this is just a homework

Comment: You could play with some perturbations of the problem, set `y(0)` to some small negative value, desingularize the equation as `y'''' = C/(eps^2+(ax^2-y)^2)`, either or both. If that works, compute a number of solutions with ever smaller perturbations and check if visually one could claim convergent behavior.

Comment: i set y(0) to -0.5 and it didn't send any warning. I plot (sol.x,sol.y) and it is a straight line!